# Series extension for concave monotonically increasing function.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose, we want to approximate the monotonically increasing and concave function (logarithmic-like family functions). We do know exactly formula for this function. All we have - several points and points values. Also we know that function has non-negative first derivative and non-positive second derivative. Of course, we have Taylor Series, but for our purpose it is important that our series shows good convergance even with 5-6 first elements and do not disconverge a lot from the points, that are located far from zero. I would like that such series would be always monotonalically increasing concave function on any steps. Is there exist such family series representation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have a specific function in mind?

Comment: An "extension" is something that *extends* the function, which does not seem to be what you are talking about. Perhaps you mean the Taylor expansion, so called because as you increase the number of terms, it expands the region where the Taylor polynomial is a good approximation of the function? All increasing polynomials are convex as you approach $+\infty$, so cannot meet the conditions you give. You could try to expand using other functions, but as we don't know what you are trying to accomplish, there is no way to know what other choices would be useful to you.

Comment: I am sorry that my language was misunderstood, I try to clarify my problem. I want to get the representation of some unknown function for me as the series. All what I know about this function is that its derivative is non-negative, and its second derivative is non-positive. At the current moments I have several points from this function and I want to approximate it with series. But I need that all elements of this representative series have the same properties with derivatives. Is there exist such series family?